# Set mark-up for bold, italic, ... in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs

Emacs org-mode has following mark-up: *bold*, /italic/, *underlined*, =code= and ~verbatim~, and, +strike-through+.

Where can I change these mark-up elements (**, //, __, ... )? For example, I'd like to change // into ## for italic, or -- for strike-through instead of ++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the docs for [`org-emphasis-alist`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el#n4256).

Note that you can customize this variable:.

`M-x customize-option <RET> org-emphasis-alist <RET>`

Comment: Done, thanks. Was looking at the wrong place (customize-face).